# How to track analytics within SDK

Tags: android, analytics, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

I am working on a SDK in Android. I need to track some events within it. Is there any 3rd party analytics SDK which can do this?

I tried Firebase and Fabric. It doesn't suit my use case because The analytics generated is associated with the APP that uses my SDK.

As the owner of the SDK I want to get my analytics regardless who ever uses my SDK.
Am I missing something in Firebase or Fabric that lets me do this?

Comment: Can you add more brief about your requirements? I am doing through fabric that's working fine. I am using contentView of fabric.

Comment: you can check clever tap i.e.  https://clevertap.com/

Comment: @Ankur_009 Are you using Fabric to track events inside your SDK project?  Doesn't the third part developer using your SDK needs to give the api key?

Comment: @bhkiran You can only report to one dashboard per app instance. This means that if they are already using Fabric it's not possible, but otherwise it is somewhat possible with the caveat that you'll need to create special installation instructions for your SDK and all package IDs will show up in different dashboards.